# how does compiler work during assignment operations?

Tags: c

Why is a assigned the value 3? Does the compiler simply take the last value from the list?

```
int a;
a=(1,2,3);
printf("%d",a);
```

How does compiler parse this statement or how it works internally?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator.

Comment: Read about comma operator in C.

Comment: because `,`(comman) is an operator so last value will be assigned to a.

Comment: [How does the Comma Operator work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work)

Answer (score 1):

Comma in `(1,2,3)` is a comma operator. It is evaluated as

```
a = ( (1,2) ,3 );
```

Comma operator is left associative. The result/value of the expression `(1,2,3)` is the value of the right operand of comma operator.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, it's because you're using the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). That means the 1 and 2 are evaluated and discarded. The three is the only thing left to be assigned. Without the parenthesis it would most likely be assigned as 1.